# How do I fix merger error (Error in fix.by(by.y, y) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column) in R on a computing cluster

Tags: r, merge, cluster-computing

I am running R code on a linux based computer cluster. I wanted to merge two SPSS data sets by "Sample_Name". Code works on R (v 3.5.2) on my laptop but I keep getting this error when I run the code through the cluster (same version R).

Error in fix.by(by.y, y) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column
Calls: merge -> merge -> merge.data.frame -> fix.by
Execution halted

I have tried every version of the merge command and looked through this whole website but nothing works. Again, this works on R but not on the cluster so I am wondering if there is something I am misunderstanding in loading in files into the cluster.

Data sets are the same class. Columns are both "characters". I tried each command with Sample_Name in single and double quotes (' ' and " ") and backslashes ( ). I want to only merge participants that are in both files.

## load in file one from my directory on the cluster

```
file_one <- read_sav('/home/mydirectory/file_one.sav')
```

## load in file two from my directory on the cluster

```
file_two <- read_sav('/home/mydirectory/file_two.sav')
```

Load commands read in the data just fine. Here is the output:

[load output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RB67o.png)

## merge by "Sample_Name" both files have this column

```
file_three <- merge (file_one, file_two, by.x = 'Sample_Name', by.y = 
'Sample_Name') 

file_three <- merge (x=file_one, y=file_two, by.x = 'Sample_Name', by.y = 
'Sample_Name') 

file_three <- merge (x=file_one, y=file_two, by.x = c('Sample_Name'), by.y 
= c('Sample_Name')

file_three <- merge (x=file_one, y=file_two, by.x = file_one$Sample_Name, 
by.y = file_two$Sample_Name)
```

Error in fix.by(by.y, y) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column Calls: merge -> merge -> merge.data.frame -> fix.by Execution halted

Comment: This is because 'file_one$Sample_Name' is not a column name of either file_one or file_two.  Could you clarify what task you want each cluster to perform? and how the initiating console is combining the results from each cluster?

Comment: I tried file_one$Sample_Name without the quotes too and it also doesn't work. I'm not sure I understand the other part of your question! I want to run this on a general purpose cluster for extra RAM. I just have to send in an R script. This is the error code I get back after the execution of the R script is halted. Does that help?

Comment: quotes or no quotes on 'file_one$Sample_Name' doesnt matter, because merge is looking for the column file_one$Sample_Name in the object file_one and it won't find it because its not there. In the object file_one the column name is Sample_Name. There is no way to refer to that column other than by using 'Sample_Name'. Your question suggests that when you run the code on your computer it works fine, but when you run it on cluster it does not. Show us exactly what you run on your computer and exactly what you run on cluster.

Comment: Okay thanks! Yes, I understand! I was just getting desperate trying different commands. I'm more concerned that the standard merge command does not work.   I run the same exact code on my computer as I do on the cluster!

Comment: so what happens on the cluster when you `file_one <- read_sav('/home/mydirectory/file_one.sav'); file_one`? Like what is the output?

Comment: That command works. This is particularly challenging as the cluster is not interactive meaning that I send in the code and it spits out and error log.

Comment: when you say 'works' be more specific please. Edit your question and post the the output from `head(file_one)` on the cluster also `head(file_one$Sample_Name)`.

Comment: Gotcha! The files are read in with no problem. See output above with column names.